# Not Showing user avatar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

HTML tag

```
<img src="storage/app/avatars/23_avatar1548246815.bmp" alt="">
```

File already exist on this path. But not showing.
And I used also this `php artisan storage:link`, but not working.
Error is Server Error 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

According to laravel documentation.

```
The Public Disk
The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

php artisan storage:link
Of course, once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

1. thing I would do is definitely use this method

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/image.png')}}">
```

to link to your asset files.

2. Shouldnt the `storage/app/avatars` be `storage/app/pubic/avatars` ?

Comment: My laravel sile url without /public. I was changed it then it is not woking.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the file exists on that path, it points that the problem is with file permissions. Change the /project/storage permissions to 777, delete the public/storage folder, and run `php artisan storage:link`, then try one more time. If no, try to give 777 permissions to `public` folder